# How to split an int

Tags: c, split

I want to read in an int. For example 001. After I want to cut up the into so that A = 0, B = 0 and C = 1. I want to do this in C. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple variables instead of an array? Also, I suggest you look up "truncate" before using it.

Comment: why don't you read a char array instead of an int, and there you have all single digits already lined up in different variables (indices). just remember to check for each to `isdigit()` and also remove the ending '\0'

Answer (score 1):

If `001` is a bit representation of your integer value `I`, then:

```
int A = (I >> 2) & 0x1
int B = (I >> 1) & 0x1
int C = I & 0x1
```

Comment: I think you meant & not &&. Also I vs. V.

Comment: Shifting is not required of course: `A = I & 0x04`, `B = I & 0x02`, `C = I & 0x01`

Comment: @Ed and if the highest bit is `1` you'll get 4 instead of 1

Comment: Bit fields like this are often used in conditionals, so `if (I & 0x04) {...}` is often used as a shortcut to avoid a shift.  Still works because 4 is non-zero.

Comment: @Karl Good note. But alexdtcom asked how to `split` it

Comment: @Elalfer: yeah, that's true.  I missed the `C should equal 1` part of the question.

Comment: @Ed:  A=I&0x04 is not the same as A=(I>>2)&0x01.  In the first example A could have the values 0 or 4, and in the last example A could have the values 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes, you must have missed my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result wanted by using modulus operator (%) and integer division (/). It's easier to understand than bitwise operators when you're starting to learn C.

```
scanf("%d", &i);    
a = i / 100;
b = (i % 100) / 10;
c = (i % 100) % 10;
```

Comment: Caveat:  this may give unexpected results when using negative numbers.  Reasonable values for -5 / 2 and -5 % 2 would be -3 and 1 or -2 and -1.  The C99 standard and upcoming C++0x standard require the latter, which isn't necessarily what you'd expect.  IIRC, C90 and C++98 didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Karl Bielefeldt's comment:

You can create a union of a char and a bitfield such as:

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char byte;
    unsigned char b0 : 1;
    unsigned char b1 : 1;
    unsigned char b2 : 1;
    unsigned char b3 : 1;
    unsigned char b4 : 1;
    unsigned char b5 : 1;
    unsigned char b6 : 1;
    unsigned char b7 : 1;
}TYPE_BYTE;

TYPE_BYTE sample_byte;
```

...then assign a value to sample_byte.byte and access each individual bit as sample_byte.b0, sample_byte.b1, etc.  The order in which the bits are assigned is implementation dependent--read your compiler manual to see how it implements bitfields.

Bitfields can also be created with larger int types.

---

Edit (2011-03-15):

Assuming that maybe you want to read in a 3-digit base-10 integer and split the three digits into three variables, here's some code that should do that.  It hasn't been tested so you might need to do some tweaking:

```
void split_base10(const unsigned int input, unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b, unsigned int *c)
{
    unsigned int x = input;

    *c = x%10;
    x /= 10;
    *b = x%10;
    *a = x/10;
}
```

Good luck!